# If $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=q$, $a_n>0$ then $a_n=o(q_1^n)$ where $q<q_1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

**Problem:**
If $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=q$, $a_n>0$ then $a_n=o(q_1^n)$ where $q<q_1$.

I have considerable time trying this, and if I don´t  make a mistake I need show that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{q_1^n}=0$$ which means that $\forall \varepsilon>o \, \text{ and } \forall n>0$ the inequality $$\left|\frac{a_n}{q_1^n}\right|<\varepsilon$$
Holds.

Now following this idea I try use the hypotesis which is that $\forall \varepsilon>0 \, \text{and} \, \forall n>0$
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-q\right|<\varepsilon$$  and use the fact that if i suppose that $0<q<q_1$ I can use that $$a_{n+1}<(\varepsilon+q)a_n$$ and use $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{q_1^n}$ y get the following inequiality $$a_{n+1}<(q a_n+\frac{a_n}{q_1^n})$$ but it fail, also I tried
part from $$\left|\frac{a_n}{q_1^n}\right| $$ and get the less than $\varepsilon$ but any  idea comes.

any hint or suggestion was useful.Thanks a lot Stack comunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $q<r<q_1$. There exists $n_0$ such tha $a_{n+1} < r a_n$ for $n \geq n_0$. Use induction to show that $a_n \leq r^{n-n_0} a_{n_0}$ for all  $n \geq n_0$. So $a_n q_1^{-n} \leq (\frac r q_1)^{n} a_{n_0}r^{-n_0}$ for all  $n \geq n_0$. Note that $(\frac r q_1)^{n}  \to 0$.

Comment: I don´t understand the part where $a_n\leq r^{n-n_0}a_{n_0}$, can you explain how you thought in it inequality ? its a trick or you infer it from $a_{n+1}<ra_n$

Comment: It is a process called iteration. If you combine  the inequalities $a_{n_0+1} \leq ra_{n_0}$ and $a_{n_0+2} \leq ra_{n_0+1}$  you get $a_{n_0+2} \leq r^{2}a_{n_0}$ and then you get  $a_{n_0+3} \leq r^{3}a_{n_0}$  in the next step, and so on.

Comment: OMG it explain all!! Its a pretty result thanks a lot $+1$

Comment: @AlanJr . The idea is that if $n> n_0$ then $a_n=a_{n_0}\prod_{j=n_0}^{n-1}\frac {a_{j+1}}{a_j}<a_{n_0}r^{n-n_0}$ if $n_0$ is large enough.